# Checkboxes to mark multiple messages disappeared in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, inbox

In Lotus Notes 8.5.3, I used to be able to put a check mark on multiple messages if I wanted to move or delete them.

How do I add this column back to the far left of my inbox?

Comment: what program do you use to read you email?

Comment: You need MUCH more detail if anyone is going to be able to answer. Start with which program it concerns.

Comment: by `notes` do you mean you are using Lotus Notes?

Comment: Sorry - Lotus Notes version 8.3.5

Comment: Sorry again! I meant v8.5.3

Comment: In the future, you can always [edit] your post to add details to it.

Answer (score 6):

Select "Preferences" from the File menu.

Click on "Basic Notes Client Configuration" in the left-hand pane.

Scroll the slider in the "Additional Options" box down to the bottom.

Click on "Show check marks in margin for selected documents".

You might have quit and restart your Notes client for this to take effect.

Comment: Glad it helped.  If you could please click to accept the answer, that would give me a few points and would create a more visual indication that the answer was correct.  Thanks!